# How to get time format to HH:mm using moment js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, time-format

I am working in React. I am troubled with getting right time format. I am selecting a time from drop down and used `moment(inputTime,HH:mm)` to format time, but this is how I get. What is the reason for it?
Is there any alternative way other than `moment(inputTime).format("HH:mm")`?

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "Tue May 04 2021 03:53:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)", _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, …}
_d: Tue May 04 2021 03:53:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
_i: "Tue May 04 2021 03:53:21 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: false
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, ordinal: ƒ, …}
_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: What's wrong with `.format("HH:mm")`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I will get an error "'isBetween' does not exist on type 'string'. when we perform the following code . inputTime.format("HH:mm").isBetween(beforeTime, afterTime);

Comment: The you don't need the formatted moment for that. Add the `.format("HH:mm")` only to where you show it in the view.

Comment: To put it another way. A moment object (what you have shown logged) wraps a Date object, which is the time value you parsed, arbitrarily set to today's date and put into the time zone of the browser. That moment object has functions like `isBetween` attached to it. It does not display the time formatted as you parsed it (technically, if you dig deep into that `_pf` property, you could probably find it, but that's implementation detail you should not depend on). When you call `format`, it takes the Date and time zone information and provides the time, formatted as desired.

Answer (score 1):

By using `moment(inputTime,HH:mm)`, you are creating a moment object. Which is why you get `Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, ...}` when printing this object to the console.

If you want to have it in the format `"HH:mm"`, it means that you want to have a string representation of your moment object in the format sus-cited. To do so, one of the correct way is to use the `format` method on the moment object.

```
var input_time = "10:46";
var date_a = moment(input_time, "HH:mm");
console.log(date_a);
>> Moment {...} // moment object
var date_a_str = date_a.format("HH:mm");
console.log(date_a_str);
>> "10:46" // string
```